# Adding vue components based on condition in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JS array formatted similar to

```
[{type:'text', data: 'some text'},{type: 'image',  data: 'link/to/image'}]
```

for the different values of `type` I have different vue components (`<text-block>`, `<image-block>`) and I want to use a `v-for` to loop over this array and based on the type, create the right vue component.

The examples for v-for show creating the same element many times like many `<li>`. Is there a way I can create different elements in a `v-for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `v-if`:

```
<div v-for="(loop, index) in loops" :key="index">
    <text-block v-if="loop.type === 'text'"></text-block>
    <image-block v-if="loop.type === 'image'"></image-block>
</div>
```

You can also use dynamic components:

```
<div v-for="(loop, index) in loops" :key="index">
    <component :is="loop.type + '-block'"></component>
</div>
```

Make sure you have imported the components and defined them on the instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this, say there's list of movies in an array:

```
<div id="app">
<ul>
<li v-for="movie in movies">{{ movie }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>

var app = new Vue({

el: '#app',
data: {
  movie: ['some movie 1', 'movie 2', 'idk movies man']
}

});

setTimeout(function() {
app.movies.push('random movie');

}, 2000);

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I need. I know I can use v-for to create li tags but I need to change the tag created based on a condition.

Comment: Alright, sorry for that answer anyways I hope you solved your issue.